# Find a new polynomial using vieta formula?

Tags: polynomials

Given that $_{ }$$x^{4}+x^{3}+px^{2}+4x-2=0$ where $p$ is a 
constant, has roots $x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}\,and\,x_{4}$

a) Find the equation whose roots are $\frac{1}{x_{1}}, 
\frac{1}{x_{2}}, \frac{1}{x_{3}}\,and\,\frac{1}{x_{4}}$

b) Given that $
x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}+x_{3}^{2}+x_{3}^{2}=\frac{1}{x_{1}^{2}}+\frac{1}{x_{2}^{2}}+\frac{1}{x_{3}^{2}}+\frac{1}{x_{4}^{2}}
$, find the value of $p$.

I know (from Vieta's formulas) that the sum of roots = -1 and product of roots = -2.
I feel that it can be solved using Vieta's theorem but I am stuck. Please help with a hint on how to proceed. Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: See the formatting tips at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Better to write out the problem here, than to make people chase it offsite.

Comment: I've finished formatting it.

Comment: Your response will be greatly appreciated.... I am having sleepless nights over this problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:  **(a)**  if $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ in $x$ with roots $x_k \ne 0$, then $Q(x)=x^nP\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ with roots $\frac{1}{x_k}$.  **(b)**  $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2=\left(\sum_k x_k\right)^2 - 2\,\sum_{i \lt j} x_ix_j\,$.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I am a high school student and I have no idea what you've written above. 
Are these formulas derived from Vieta's formulas for the quartic? If so, then how have they been derived?

Comment: @JaneT **(a)** $x^{4}+x^{3}+px^{2}+4x-2=0 \iff x^4 \left(1 + \frac{1}{x}+p\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^2+4\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^3-2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^4\right) = 0\,$, so the polynomial with roots $\frac{1}{x_k}$ is $-2x^4+4x^3+px^2+x+1$.  **(b)** $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2$ $=\left(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4\right)^2$ $- 2\,\left(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_1x_4+x_2x_3+x_2x_4+x_3x_4\right)\,$ where both terms on the RHS are known by Vieta's.

Comment: Many thanks for your prompt reply, I now understand part (a), however, for part (b) I am unsure on how to proceed with the equation which you have provided (which I fully understand). How does this equation help in calculation of parameter p?

Comment: @JaneT Using Vieta's relations, it follows that $\,x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2 = (-1)^2 - 2p\,$. Now that you know the polynomial with roots $\,1/x_k\,$, do the same to calculate $\,1/x_1^2+1/x_2^2+1/x_3^2+1/x_4^2\,$. Equate the two, and you get a simple equation to solve for $\,p\,$.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much for your help I really appreciate it.

Comment: @JaneT Glad you worked it out.